# How to find if the previous character is the same

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a calculator.

My problem is the buttons could be double clicked creating 2 of the same characters next to each other (Example: `2++2`). I want to remove the second plus sign.

So far I've managed to use this:

```js
if(!y.includes("+")) {
  summed.push("+")
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = summed.join('')
}
```

But this will only allow 1 plus sign and would disable any other. My intended solution should be this (3+3+3) and not this (3++3). Hopefully this is understandable.

Comment: Check whether the last element in the array is the same sign or not and then decide to push it.

Comment: @aksappy omg thx so much i didnt even think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check last character `y[y.length - 1]` is not `+`.

```js
if(y && y.length >0  && y[y.length - 1] !== "+") {
  summed.push("+")
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = summed.join('')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this:

```
let math = [...]

if(math[math.length - 1] == "+") {
// do not allow to append another +
}
```

Comment: where do you get undefined?